# Is it safe to upload my Django project to GitHub?

Tags: python, django, git, security, github

Will uploading my Django project to GitHub make my superuser (created with `python manage.py createsuperuser`) vulnerable?

I used a sensitive password with the superuser I created and I do not want it to be compromised by uploading the source code to GitHub.

The website itself does not contain any sensitive code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, and as long as your `settings.py` does not include sensitive information, uploading your Django project to GitHub will not compromise your super user account. Your user information is stored in your database, which should not be included in your Git repository.

The most likely situation where this *might* be a problem is if you are using SQLite, a file-based database. If you are, make sure that your database file is not (and has never been) checked into your repository.

Comment: Won't the credentials for the database itself be accessible though?

Comment: @L3viathan, it is never a good idea to commit database credentials, but thanks for the reminder that many developers do this anyway. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: If I change my admin account password (which is the only account on my server), would the old password be able to compromised?  FYI I haven't committed anything since creating the admin account.

Comment: @kenschnall, the admin password only exists in your database. As long as you don't include your database itself (e.g. an SQLite file) or your database credentials (e.g. in `settings.py`) you shouldn't have to worry.

Comment: The OP specifically asked about superuser passwords, but it seems to me that settings.py contains information about the project that would be useful to a hypothetical attacker. Certainly SECRET_KEY should not be committed, and I worry a little about ALLOWED_HOSTS and any HTTPS flags. What do you think?

Comment: @cxrodgers, it's hard to completely answer this question since `settings.py` _can_ contain just about anything. I agree that `SECRET_KEY` should not be made public, but I would argue that it doesn't belong in `settings.py` anyway. IMO it should be configured some other way, for example through an environment variable à la [12 Factor](http://12factor.net/). This is why I said "as long as your `settings.py` does not include sensitive information".

Comment: Is it possible and safe to -for practical reasons- just upload everything and then, in GitHub, edit settings.py, i.e. deleting SECRET_KEY and DATABASES?

Comment: @101is5, why would you do that? What benefit does it have? In any case, it depends what you mean by "safe". You'd want to change your `SECRET_KEY` and database credentials since the old ones would still exist in the version history; removing them in one commit is not sufficient.

Comment: @Chris I'm fairly new to github. So I guess clean up `settings.py` before uploading is the way to go.